# Android buttons issues

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am making an piano app, in which there is nine buttons and when we touch the button each buttons play a different sound. But now the problems are-

1) when we touch the button it play the sound of that button only and it didn't play the sound of next buttons on moving the fingers.

2)If i use ACTION_UP to stop sound then at these event when we lift the finger from button it stop the sound without finishing the complete sound of that button.

```
   public class Piano_view extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Button sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, sound5, sound6, sound7, sound8,
            sound9;

    MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3, mp4, mp5, mp6, mp7, mp8, mp9;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.piano_view);
        initMpFiles();
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);





        sound1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        sound2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second);
        sound3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        sound4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        sound5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        sound6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        sound7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        sound8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        sound9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        sound1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound3.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound4.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound5.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound6.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound7.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound8.setOnTouchListener(this);
        sound9.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private void initMpFiles() {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.a4);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.b4);
        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.c4);
        mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.c5);
        mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.e4);
        mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.b4);
        mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.f4);
        mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.d4);
        mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(Piano_view.this, R.raw.g4);
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.one:

                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp1.start();
                    mp1.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }

                break;
            case R.id.second:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp2.start();
                    mp2.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.three:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp3.start();
                    mp3.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.four:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp4.start();
                    mp4.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;



            case R.id.five:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp5.start();
                    mp5.seekTo(0);

                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.six:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp6.start();
                  mp6.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.seven:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp7.start();
                   mp7.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.eight:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                 mp8.start();
                    mp8.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.nine:
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mp9.start();
                    mp9.seekTo(0);
                    v.setPressed(true);
                    return true;
                }


                    break;








        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case,you should not use Button.Draw a view contains **"9 Buttons"** and handle the touch event by your self.

Comment: thanks and can you please send me a link which contains example in which we draw a view which contains buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onTouch and start the music in a new thread. If you are moving the thread keeps running. 
You can use a handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

And in your onTouch listener. Im not shure if it is working with the ACTION_DOWN. You could also add ACTION_MOVE to also detect moving.

```
                    int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - coords[0];
                    int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - coords[1];
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    if(put your test with the coodinates here){
                        handler.post(runMp1);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            break;
```

Now you need to check that the touch corridates are within the button coridnates. A example could be

```
 int M1right = (int) button.getRight();
 int M1top = (int) button.getTop();
 int M1left = (int) button.getLeft();
 int M1bottom = (int) button.getBottom();

 if(x < M1right && x > M1left && y < M1bottom && y > M1top)
```

Then you need a thread

```
private Runnable runMp1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mp1.start();
        mp1.seekTo(0);
        v.setPressed(true);
    }
};
```

Additionaly you could add a bool var, which is set to fase until the sound finished. Only if this var is true the handler starts.

Hope that solves your problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your the ans but can you please explain me it in detail that how can i use ACTION_UP to start music in new thread for all the buttons

Comment: is my awnser detailed enought? Or are there any questions?